# Liferay page permissions are not working in site template?

Tags: liferay, lifecycle

I have created a site template with three pages (P1,P2,P3) and I have created a "site" and it render from the site template.
Site admin only access the three pages(P1,P2,P3) and normal user can view the three pages(Site Membership). But how to restrict the normal user only view two pages (P1 and P3).
I set the permissions at the "Page level" but site member also view the page "P2".

Some one please help me how to restrict the Page "P2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the following problem. You want to set the permissions at the page level over P2. Before doing anything, You have something like this:

[image: Default permissions]

Then, you changed the permission to SITE MEMBER over P2, unchecking the permission view

[image: Unchecking view in site member]

But when you go to your site, all SITE MEMBERS can see the page 2.

Also You need to uncheck the permission for Guest (unauthenticated users).

[image: unchecking view Guest]

After that, the site admin will be able to see P1,P2,P3 but site members only will be able to see P1,P3

Comment: Yes I am doing the same,Page"P2" disabled for the site member but few pages are not working at the "Page Level Permissions".If any other way to hide the pages for the site members

Comment: do you uncheck permission guest too?

Comment: Yes I have unchecked for the guest permission for all my pages. If I missing any thing at the permission level?. I have "site owner" permission only.

Comment: why don`t you try to download a new liferay (clean), configure it only with: site template, site, two users to test (you will see that the configuration work),and then add the rest of configuration until you figure out what part of your configuration is failing. I have the feeling that You may have changed some other configuration.

Comment: Thank you,now It is working. I have created new template and new site. The site owner can enable/disable pages for site members.